# How to do a simple post request on react given an api

Tags: reactjs, rest

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {



  handleSubmit(event) {
    axios.post('http://localhost:3050/login', {
      "username": "username",
      "password": "password"
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {

      return(

        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

      );
  }

}

export default App;
```

I am currently playing around with rest api / react and I couldn't get this basic submit to work. So using postman "http://localhost:3050/login" as a post request I sent this json

```
{
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password"
}
```

The response body is a 200 OK and returns

```
{ 
    "friends": 0,
    "id": "555"
}
```

So that's what postman gives. I am trying to mimic this on the code above so it post {"friends": 0,"id": "555"} in the console log if I were to submit. But it doesn't do anything. I am confused

Comment: What happens when you click button?

Comment: Nothing at all : https://gyazo.com/2f41b99c964f55f34f55e72ae0eb0ddf

Comment: I don't see any issue in your code, might be your server is not running. Make sure your server is running and you are accessing correct URL.

Comment: Thats odd. My backend server IS running on that link as I'm making postman calls while attempting this

Comment: You publish the password value in your React app? Are these user input parameters?

Comment: Oh no. There are no inputs. I'm sending the json. The problem was CORS was blocking it or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3050/login',null, {params:{
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password"
   }}).
  then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: xhr.js:166 POST http://localhost:3050/login?username=username&password=password 400 (Bad Request)

localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3050/?username=username&password=password' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Above are the errors. Could be because I never used parameters and just sent a json? Works on postman

Comment: Run chrome of dev in unsecured mode like:  Right click on desktop, add new shortcut
Add the target as "[PATH_TO_CHROME]\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp
Click OK. And push your site link on this instance of chrome

Comment: Your suggestion worked the code didn't need changing though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default browser willblock the request to another domain. In your case you are requesting to http://localhost:3050 from http://localhost:3000. Since the domain names are different CORS will rise. To reolve it you have to enable the CORS in the server which running on port 3050.
If your using node-express as backend server, then use below line to overcome the CORS

```
app.all('/*', (req, res, next) => {

  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,token, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers');
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.sendStatus(204);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Comment: My backend server is in java